# Suddenly an image file is corrupt. Any chance of repair/recovery?

Tags: lightroom, error, import, file-recovery

So I've tried comparing a few images I've taken recently and this happened.

[image: Stripe Image]

I was in the **Library Module** comparing two images (X|Y Icon) and this happened on one of my shots. I've checked and my **GPU Acceleration** is turned off (had that be a problem). I've also removed the **Smart Preview** and rebuilt it, with no success.

I've also checked using a RAW viewer that the image was corrupt. Is there anyway I can recover the image? The JPEG is at least intact.

**UPDATE:** Re-importing fixes it initially then it reverts to that state.

**UPDATE2:** I've compared it against my backup, the md5 and crc32 hashes are identical and the file size are the same.

**UPDATE3:** Importing it in a fresh catalog fails and exporting it generates the same result.

**UPDATE4:** Tested it with different RAW tool and it fails. **Exiftool** suggests all info is intact at least. I've removed the image off of my SD card so I don't have the original unfortunately.

**UPDATE5:** My other backup works and the hash check is different from the first backup. This solves my problem and makes for a simple answer of just use an older backup. That being said are there tool or techniques to recover corrupt images?

Comment: Does this file have something special compared to your other images? Have you another "RAW viewer" so you could try to see if Lightroom is the problem? Maybe your RAW is corrupted but the embedded preview JPEG isn't (and LR shows you the preview JPEG before generating one from the processed RAW).

Comment: regarding your UPDATE2 : can you import your backup with success ?

Comment: @Oliver Nope neither the original nor the new copy works. I'm unsure what to say at this point.

Comment: Try with another RAW viewer (maybe the one native to your camera). If you still have this problem, your RAW is probably corrupted.

Comment: @Oliver Confirmed it's a bad file and my first backup is corrupt. My 2nd backup with my failing hard drive has a good copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repair "partially" corrupted raw (cr2) files?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41187/how-do-i-repair-partially-corrupted-raw-cr2-files)

Comment: Related : http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27103/how-can-i-repair-a-corrupt-nef-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair a corrupt .nef file?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27103/how-can-i-repair-a-corrupt-nef-file)

Answer (score -5):

Never mind, a third-party JPEG repair software can help you. Read this blog to check the review of JPEG repair software https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-and-fix-corrupted-images/

I will recommend you to go for Stellar jpeg repair software. I used it and it worked for me. Before buying the software, try its demo http://www.stellarinfo.com/jpeg-repair.php

**Note**: I am not the representative of Stellar or the blog raymond.cc. If you find the better option then, share it.

Comment: In this case, there is a perfectly fine JPEG file but the RAW is corrupt. Will this software help with that?

Comment: Software doesn't repair RAW files. You can convert the raw file to jpeg format and repair from it.

Comment: That makes no sense. If the RAW file is corrupt, you won't be able to convert it to a JPEG that need any repair.