# Lightroom messing with photo when importing RAW

Tags: canon, lightroom, raw

When I'm trying to import to Lightroom CC 2015 my photos taken in my Canon 5DS using the format RAW(cr2 files) some photos are being messed.

I've already tried to upgrade the Camera Raw codec to version 9.8 and still not working.

My PC has a NVIDIA 750g ti, Win10 64, Lightroom CC 2015 64.

Could someone help me with that?

This is what's happening...

[image: This is what's happening]

[UPDATE] - It's not the same question was marked [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59709/cr2-pictures-damaged-and-corrupted), once I don't get any message from Lightroom, telling me my files are in fact corrupted.

Comment: It's not clear what we're looking at in your image. Is that a single messed-up image or a photo of the screen? Can you show what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Is this happening with *all* files from your 5Ds or only with *some* of them?

Comment: It's happening with some of the files, basically around 15% of the files... some parts of the photo seems perfect but some parts looks like the image posted.

the messed part is the photo, not the screen. and not all photos, only some parts of some photos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.CR2 pictures damaged and corrupted](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59709/cr2-pictures-damaged-and-corrupted)

Comment: @mattdm It's not the same case, I don't get any message when I import the files

Comment: @andrepaulo As I understand the other question, most in that case get that error and aren't even shown, but the remainder load and are corrupt in a way similar to your issue — and most importantly, I think the _answer_ is the same. You've got a data corruption issue.

Comment: See also [Why do images get “corrupted”?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-images-get-corrupted), which is about JPEG images on the face of it, but at the lower level that doesn't matter.

Comment: If you really believe that the problem is Lightroom "messing" with your files rather than the files being corrupt, you might try opening them in other software, like the free and open source [RawTherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/downloads).

Comment: I concur with them looking corrupt. As you have CC, have you tried opening the RAW files directly with photoshop? Do they look the same purple mess?

Comment: Also can you view the images ok on back of the camera?

Comment: @CrazyDino I have no photoshop on this computer, only LR CC 2015. But I tried opening the same files in other computers, and the files open without mess, also, in the back of the camera, files are perfect

Comment: @andrepaulo I suggest updating the question with this information. What software were you using on other computers? If lightroom what was there version/build and what is your version/build? (dont have LR available at mo so don't know how Adobe donates minor versions)

Comment: @andrepaulo What you see on the back of the camera is the preview jpeg generated when you take the shot, not the contents of the raw data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repair "partially" corrupted raw (cr2) files?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41187/how-do-i-repair-partially-corrupted-raw-cr2-files)

Answer (score 1):

It is a codec problem between the Canon codec and Lightroom's one. Uninstall both and reinstall only lightrooms again.

Comment: I reinstalled the windows 10 and also the lightroom, and the problem persists.

Comment: Didn't work even doing it again.